# wpf ContextMenu auto scroll to menuitem on keypress?

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I'm modifying the style for a ContextMenu and trying to implement scrolling so that when the user presses a letter, the contextmenu will auto scroll to the first menuitem beginning with that letter.

Is there a setting build in somewhere that I'm missing or do I need to process PreviewKeyDown events?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish something similar to this by prefixing the desired letter in the `Header` text with an underscore `_`

Like so:

```
<MenuItem Header="_Add" /> <!-- Will activate when 'A' is pressed -->
<MenuItem Header="Re_move" /> <!-- Will activate when 'M' is pressed -->
```

See [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748845(v=vs.85).aspx) for more info

Comment: is it also possible to not show the '_' on the menu item itself?

Comment: Is the underscore actually showing or do you mean the underline on the text?

Comment: I mean the underline in the text is what I want to hide.

Comment: @mtissington I am not sure if that is possible.  Perhaps you can override it with a style or with `TextDecoration`, but I have never tried.

Comment: Figured it out - instead of using the '_' I can use AccessKeyManager.Register as I add the items.